# How to reduce each individual ingredient according to another seq of 'applied' ingredients in a recipe

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So I have a soup that is compromised of a sequence of ingredient.
I need to determine what ingredients I still need to apply to the soup, based on a sequence of mixtures I have already added to the soup that I am making.

```
case class Ingredient(name: String)
case class Mixture(ingredient: Ingredient, amount: Int)

// ingredient required to make soup
val i1 = Ingredient("water")
val i2 = Ingredient("salt")
val i3 = Ingredient("sugar")

val soupRequirements = Seq(Mixture(i1, 100), Mixture(i2, 200), Mixture(i3, 50))

println(soup)


val addedIngrediants = Seq(Mixture(i1, 50), Mixture(i2, 200), Mixture(i3, 40))

def determineWhatsLeft(soupRequirements: Seq[Mixture], addedIncredients: Seq[Mixture]): Seq[Mixture] = ???
```

Reference: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/X6PIG7zYQOGuZX7zcebgRQ

How exactly can I reduce each mixture by the correct amount in a functional way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First define way of reducing two `Mixture`s via infix operator

```
implicit class ReduceMixtures(a: Mixture) {
  def +(b: Mixture): Mixture =
    if (a.ingredient == b.ingredient) Mixture(a.ingredient, a.amount - b.amount)
    else a
}
```

Note how if the `ingredient`s do not match we return `a` unchanged. Now we can implement `determineWhatsLeft` using `foldLeft`

```
def determineWhatsLeft(soupRequirements: Seq[Mixture], addedIncredients: Seq[Mixture]): Seq[Mixture] = {
  addedIngredients.foldLeft(soupRequirements) { case (acc, next) => acc.map(_ + next) }
}
```

Using `foldLeft` the order does not matter, however if the order of `soupRequirements` and `addedIngredients` was always mirrored then we could `zip` and `map` like so

```
def determineWhatsLeft(soupRequirements: Seq[Mixture], addedIncredients: Seq[Mixture]): Seq[Mixture] =
  (soupRequirements zip addedIngredients).map { case (a, b) => a + b }
```

---

[Semigroup](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/semigroup.html) seems to be the least powerful abstraction fitting the requirement

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.Semigroup

implicit object mixtureSemigroup extends Semigroup[Mixture] {
  def combine(a: Mixture, b: Mixture): Mixture =
    if (a.ingredient == b.ingredient) Mixture(a.ingredient, a.amount - b.amount)
    else a
}

implicit object seqMixtureSemigroup extends Semigroup[Seq[Mixture]] {
  def combine(soupRequirements: Seq[Mixture], addedIncredients: Seq[Mixture]): Seq[Mixture] =
    addedIngredients.foldLeft(soupRequirements) { case (acc, next) =>
      acc.map(_ |+| next)
    }
}

soupRequirements |+| addedIngredients
```

Comment: Thanks.  Say there is a case where in ReduceMixtures I want to remove the Mixture.  Is there a way I can bring in Some/None into the logic?  Like if the amount gets below 0.

Comment: @Blankman Consider `(soupRequirements |+| addedIngredients) filter (_.amount > 0)`

Comment: Can you use Some/Option inside of a fold somehow?

Comment: I want the ability to remove an item completely from the accumulation process during the fold process, is that possible?